# UIView size is growing improperly in iPhone 6 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autosize, size-classes

My ViewController frame size is 320x568 for iPhone 5s, but when i run it in iPhone 6 simulator view size going to be 430x854. I've tried using size classes but not sure if i used it rightly.
I have scrollview and pagecontroller for sliding and all items lose their formation.

Here it is logged values

```
view: x:0.000000 y:0.000000 w:430.000000 h:854.000000
```

Comment: Is there any place where you are adding height to your view...

Comment: No, i am checking in the viewDidLoad

Comment: interesting point is iPhone 6 width - 320 = 55, 375 + 55 = 430, i think it is growing twice both left and right

Comment: Yes you have a good point... try and solve it that way I was also thinking from where the height is increasing...

Answer (score 0):

I restarted xCode, then it worked correctly, thanks.

Comment: hello, i am facing the same issue.. i restarted my xcode and also PC.. but it doesnt work for me.. can you please help me on it

Comment: Actually i haven't done anything special as a solution for this issue, i 'd tried some constraint changes but those didn't work. Restarting xCode solved it.